# Detecting and removing substrings from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm working with URLs and sometimes end up with random repeated phrases in them that are throwing off my scripts. I'd like to remove the duplicates.

So, I start with something like this:

```
url = "https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?fn=email&uaid=51e2193a466c4846a4317b94931b9086&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&lc=1033&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&id=38936&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US&mkt=en-US"
```

And want to convert that to:

```
url = "https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?fn=email&uaid=51e2193a466c4846a4317b94931b9086&lc=1033&id=38936&mkt=en-US"
```

All of the solutions I've looked at rely on the spaces between words or the repeating pattern coming at the beginning of the string.  In my situation, the repeating pattern(s) don't have those boundaries to base my grouping on.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would do a `split("&")` and see what's in there, then maybe make a `set()` from that and hopefully you should end up with unique parameters `("lc=1033", "id=38936", "mkt=en-US")` that you can then add back one by one to the "root" string that is I guess `.split("&")[0]`.

Comment: I should have clarified that ... the '&' isn't always the repeating identifier ... sometimes it's '%', sometimes it's '=' and sometimes is just an alphanumeric character. That's why I haven't been able to use a the split function to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is going to be to extract the query string and `split` it into separate parts on the `&` character; the last step is going to be to `join` the parts back together with `&`.

Assuming the duplicates always appear adjacent to each other like in your example input, you can filter them out using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to retain the original order:

```py
import itertools

def remove_duplicate_params(url):
    path, _, query_string = url.partition('?')
    parts = query_string.split('&')
    return path + '?' + '&'.join(k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(parts))

# 'https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?fn=email&uaid=51e2193a466c4846a4317b94931b9086&lc=1033&id=38936&mkt=en-US'
```

If the duplicates might not be adjacent, and you don't need to preserve the order of the parameters in the query string, you can use `set` to remove the duplicates:

```py
def remove_duplicate_params(url):
    path, _, query_string = url.partition('?')
    parts = query_string.split('&')
    return path + '?' + '&'.join(set(parts))

# 'https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?fn=email&mkt=en-US&lc=1033&id=38936&uaid=51e2193a466c4846a4317b94931b9086'
```

Comment: I should have clarified that ... the '&' isn't always the repeating identifier ... sometimes it's '%', sometimes it's '=' and sometimes is just an alphanumeric character.  That's why I haven't been able to use a the split function to solve this issue.

Comment: @Guimoute Unlike `dict`, `set` doesn't guarantee to preserve insertion order. The part including the URL path has to stay at the start; I've edited to give a version using `set`.

Comment: `parts = url.split("&")` `clean_url = parts[0] + "&".join(param for param in set(parts[1:]))` works fine if the parameters can be interverted.

Comment: @Guimoute It's a little better to partition on the `?` first, in case the first parameter after the `?` is a duplicate. But your solution should work otherwise, yes.

Comment: Absolutely, I missed the `?` in that long url to be honest.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked nicely and now I have a new module to study!